# Add a Polymer paper-dropdown-menu to a page from javascript?

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to add a `paper-dropdown-menu` into my page from JavaScript. However, when I do it this way, it ends up malformed on the page - the list items display by default and do not collapse back into the list.

This is the basic structure of a paper-dropdown-menu, so it looks like I need to create 3 elements nested within each other and then append it to my target div...

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Type">
 <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
  <paper-item>Test</paper-item>
 </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

To that end, I wrote this so far:

**index.html**

```
<paper-button id="AddList" on-tap="_addList">Add List</paper-button>
<div id="ListGoesHere"></div>
```

**app.js**

```
app._addList() = function(e) {
  // creating the dropdown container
  var elDropdown = document.createElement('paper-dropdown-menu');
  elDropdown.label = 'Type';

  // creating the paper-menu to go inside the paper-dropdown-menu
  var elMenu = document.createElement('paper-menu');
  elMenu.id = 'ProjectType';
  elMenu.className = 'dropdown-content';

  // creating one item (option)
  var elItem = document.createElement('paper-item');
  elItem.value = 'test';
  elItem.innerHTML = 'Test';

  // nesting the item inside of the menu
  elMenu.appendChild(elItem);

  // nesting the menu inside the dropdown
  elDropdown.appendChild(elMenu);

  // attaching the new dropdown element to the page/DOM
  document.querySelector('#ListGoesHere').appendChild(elDropdown);
};
```

It just doesn't seem to be nesting these elements properly - the paper-menu appears outside of the paper-dropdown-menu element and does not react at all when clicking the paper-dropdown-menu. I've done similar things with other Polymer elements such as paper-inputs and paper-textareas and they worked as expected. Is there something different/special about the dropdown elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is not a good way to add elements to the polymer dom dynamically, this still does not  render ok and the binding does not works.

The right way to implement this I think is to make list of dropDown menus and create dom-repeat template ,this is easier way.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{dropMenus}}">
   <paper-dropdown-menu label="Type">

       <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item}}">
            <paper-item>{{item}}</paper-item>
          </template>
        </paper-menu>

   </paper-dropdown-menu>
  </template>
```

And append to the itemsArray item by using the push method

```
  this.set('dropMenus',[['item1','item2'],['item1','item2'],['item1','item2']]);
```

or if you use app

```
  app.set('dropMenus',[['item1','item2'],['item1','item2'],['item1','item2']]);
```

Comment: Where would I put something like this? I tried creating a custom element out of it, but it just crashes my app.

Comment: Okay, I did get it to show up in a custom element, but I had tried to create a ready function that would push some default options in there and that is the part that was crashing it. `ready: function() { this.push('dropMenus',['test']); }`

Comment: try this 
ready: function() { this.set('dropMenus',[['test']]); }

array inside array

Comment: Thanks for checking but I still get the same error. It looks like Polymer.Base._addFeature.push does not receive an array. The error is _TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined_ - I'm still trying different things.

Comment: I think that you didnt init the array.
You try to push element and their is no array.
https://jsfiddle.net/388pwosa/
this is working

Comment: That got rid of the error, but it isn't actually generating a dropdown list at all, for example, if I place `<menu-example></menu-example>` tags in my page. I don't want to keep bothering you, though. I'll keep trying.

Comment: you have all the paper-menu,paper-item,paper-dropdown-menu files in the correct location?
I tried it and this creates drop down menus

Comment: I finally got frustrated and retyped everything from scratch and then it worked... When I did a comparison, I found one difference - this.set instead of this.push. I see it's already updated in your answer - I just hadn't noticed there was a difference, I apologize. Thanks so much for your help today, this works beautifully now, and gives me some new insight into making more custom elements in the future :)